# biblatex/biber: using strings macros from one file in multiple refsections

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a `@string` definition stored in a file `abrv.bib`.  I would like to combine this abbreviations file with a bib file 'entry.bib' containing an entry to create a list of references for a particular section of my document.  I have been able to do this successfully with `biblatex` for one section, but am finding it quite difficult to do for multiple sections.  I have included a small example that illustrates my problem.

My `@string` definition in `abrv.bib` is being used in `entry1.bib` and `entry2.bib`.  The output from `biber` indicates that `abrv.bib` is found when processing section 1, but not for section 2.  The resulting document will contain correct references for section 1, but contains the references with section 2 with blanks where the `@string` macros are supposed to expand.

How can I get `abrv.bib` to be used for both references sections?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug?

I am using pdflatex from TeX Live 2012, biber v1.6, and biblatex 2.6.

file.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addsectionbib[datatype=bibtex]{./abrv.bib}
\addsectionbib[datatype=bibtex]{./entry1.bib}
\addsectionbib[datatype=bibtex]{./entry2.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{refsection}[abrv,entry1]
  \nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=1,title=\null]

\section{Section 2}

\begin{refsection}[abrv,entry2]
  \nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=2,title=\null]

\end{document}
```

abrv.bib

```
@string{AUTHOR = "Author"}
```

entry1.bib

```
@book{ key1,
  author = AUTHOR,
  title = "Title1",
  publisher = "Publisher",
  year = 2013
}
```

entry2.bib

```
@book{ key2,
  author = AUTHOR,
  title = "Title2",
  publisher = "Publisher",
  year = 2013
}
```

Biber output:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.6
INFO - Logfile is 'file.blg'
INFO - Reading 'file.bcf'
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 1
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 2
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 1
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'abrv.bib' for section 1
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'abrv.bib'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'entry1.bib' for section 1
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'entry1.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nty' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Processing section 2
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'abrv.bib' for section 2
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'entry2.bib' for section 2
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'entry2.bib'
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/q5/gq1zmtqd46b4fvqx73m25hw00000gn/T/SZ8HSBpKix/entry2.bib_8957.utf8, line 2, warning: undefined macro "AUTHOR"
WARN - The field 'author' in entry 'key2' cannot be null, deleting it
INFO - Overriding locale 'en_US.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nty' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Writing 'file.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
INFO - Output to file.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 2
```

Comment: It seems to me that your MWE is fine and possibly this is a bug in biber... In fact, if I change the backend to `backend=bibtex` and compile the bibliographies with bibtex, all is fine (your `@string` is seen in both of them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that by default `biber` clears bibtex macros between refsections. I have changed this default and added a new option `clrmacros` for version 1.7 which you can get from the SF "development" folder.

EDIT: I have just updated `biblatex` 2.7 dev version with a fix which makes global bib resources work better with this so you can do (i.e. it fixes your case II).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addglobalbib{test3.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{refsection}[test3-1.bib]
  \nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=1,title=\null]

\section{Section 2}

\begin{refsection}[test3-2.bib]
  \nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[section=2,title=\null]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of what's happening underneath the refsection calls, but it seems that clearing the macros would be fine as long as the macros in `abrv.bib` were reprocessed for the next refsection (as it is specified as a resource in both calls to `\begin{refsection}`).  

However, to clarify your changes in 1.7: would I continue to specify `abrv.bib` as a resource in both calls to `\begin{refsection}`?  Or, as an alternative, can I declare `abrv.bib` as a global resource that will now be used by both refsection?  

I appreciate the help!

Comment: After trying out 1.7, my original MWE works as intended - thanks!  Some additional notes with respect to the MWE for those curious.  I) Excluding `abrv.bib` as a resource in the second refsection will also work, as the macros carry over from the first refsection.  II) Specifying a global `abrv.bib` and not explicitly specifying it as a resource in  refsections causes the first refsection to miss the macros.  III) Specifying a global `abrv.bib` will work if at least the first refsection specifies `abrv.bib` as a resource.

Comment: I have updated the solution with a note about a `biblatex` (not biber) fix which addresses another aspect of this (your case II - which should work).